# Fieldtype display_field() function converting to htmlentities()?

Tags: add-on-development, fieldtype

I'm having some trouble where my `display_fields()` function is converting my json encoded data from `$data` into `htmlentities()`.

Here's my function:

```
function display_field($data)
{
    error_log($data);
}
```

Return:

```
[{&quot;approved&quot;:true}]
```

Stored in database as:

```
[{"approved":true}]
```

Comment: I also toyed around with the `field_ft_xxx` field in the database setting it to "none" and `NULL` which produced the same result. :(

Comment: I would suggest searching out another field type that stores it's data using JSON and see how that handles it...

Answer (score 2):

The comments on the [official documentation](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/fieldtypes.html#9237) page note the following:

> Just a note that on `display_field` the data has htmlspeciachars on it if you’re trying to `deserialize` or `decode_json` so make sure you do this:
>
> `htmlspecialchars_decode($data)`
>
> Before you try and decode it.

So to apply that same thing in your case, you'd need:

`function display_field($data)
{
    error_log( htmlspecialchars_decode($data) );
}`

Comment: I'll note that the comment is from 2010. I'm not able to look at the codebase at the moment, but I'll update this answer when I've verified if htmlspecialchars is still automatically applied.